# Angular-chart.js graph highlight

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I am working on AngularJS base web application.
I used Angular-highchart.js to draw line graph.
In this application, there are 80 of graph lines in a page. So, I want to highlight graph line when users click it.

But I couldn't find out proper options to highlight graph. Are there any options to highlight graph line when users click it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use series' `click` event for this:

```
  plotOptions: {
    line: {
      events: {
        click: function() {
          this.update({
            lineWidth: 5 // increase the width of the line
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/2j5fedwh/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.events

Comment: Can I use it in Angular-chart.js?

Comment: You can use it in angular-**highcharts** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts)